# Unable to float image side by side of tables in headerbox baposter

Tags: posters, baposter

I am unable to place the image to the right of the tables or vice versa. How should I do it.

Below is MWE.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\selectcolormodel{cmyk}

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored


\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}

\newenvironment{boenumerate}
  {\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf\theenumi.}}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}


\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.45}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.25}

\begin{poster}
{
grid=false,
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=darkgreen, % Border color
headerColorOne=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=false, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.11\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
{}
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
{
\textsf %Sans Serif
{Some title which may be very long}
} % Poster title
{\sf\vspace{0.3em}\\
\vspace{0.1em}\\

}



\headerbox{1. Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0, span=3}{
\begin{tabular}{|P{4.0cm}|P{3.0cm}|P{3cm}|}
\hline
one & two & three \\
\hline
1   &   2 & 3 \\
\hline
1   &   2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}

\begin{tabular}{|P{4.0cm}|P{3.0cm}|P{3cm}|}
\hline
one & two & three \\
\hline
1   &   2 & 3 \\
\hline
1   &   2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\includegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{example-image-a}
}

\headerbox{6. Conclusions}{name=conclusion,column=1,below=introduction,span=2,above=bottom}{

We proved that DeCAF is a significant improvement over the SEA algorithm, a popular method for comparing sets of ligands.
\begin{boenumerate}\compresslist
    \item DeCAF gives better results for 23 out of 35 receptors.
    \item For targets with easily separable active and inactive datasets, SEA and DeCAF give similar results.
    \item In cases in which SEA fails to identify active molecules, our method performs substantially better.
\end{boenumerate}
 
}


\headerbox{7. References}{name=references,column=0,span=1,below=introduction,above=bottom}{


%\small % Reduce the font size in this block
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
%\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{poster} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**First edit**

After removing/commenting paragraph break, it still does not solve the problem completely. The figure is on the right side but its still center aligned horizontally which is weird.

[image]

Comment: you have a paragraph break (blank line) between them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, It still does not solve the problem. the image alignment is weird. I expected it to be top-aligned. I don't have text in this headerbox only 2 tables and 1 image.

Comment: the image you showed is what I would expect. tabular is centred by default unless you use `[b]`  so the centre of the table and bottom of the image sit on the same baseline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the two tabulars on a top aligned minipage `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}`, and do the same for the figure.

The top alignment of a minipage is with respect the baseline of first item in the minipage.

A zero-height invisible element like `\vspace{0pt}` will then force the alignment to the "real" top of the minipage.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
    
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored   

\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}

\newenvironment{boenumerate}
{\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf\theenumi.}}
    {\end{enumerate}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
        
\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.45}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.25}

\begin{poster}
    {
        grid=false,
        headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
        colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
        bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
        bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
        borderColor=darkgreen, % Border color
        headerColorOne=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
        headerColorTwo=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
        headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
        boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
        textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
        eyecatcher=false, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
        headerheight=0.11\textheight, % Height of the header
        headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
        headershade=plain,
        headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
        %textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
        linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
    }
    {}
    %
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    {
        \textsf %Sans Serif
        {Some title which may be very long}
    } % Poster title
    {\sf\vspace{0.3em}\\
        \vspace{0.1em}\\
        
    }
                    
    \headerbox{1. Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0, span=3}{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr 4cm+3cm+3cm + 6\tabcolsep} % added <<<
            \vspace{0pt} % needed <<<<<
            \begin{tabular}{|P{4.0cm}|P{3.0cm}|P{3cm}|}
                \hline
                one & two & three \\
                \hline
                1   &   2 & 3 \\
                \hline
                1   &   2 & 3 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}           
            \vspace{1em}
            
            \begin{tabular}{|P{4.0cm}|P{3.0cm}|P{3cm}|}
                \hline
                one & two & three \\
                \hline
                1   &   2 & 3 \\
                \hline
                1   &   2 & 3 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}% added <<<
            \vspace{0pt} % needed <<<<<
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
        \end{minipage} \hfill
    }
    \headerbox{6. Conclusions}{name=conclusion,column=1,below=introduction,span=2,above=bottom}{
        
        We proved that DeCAF is a significant improvement over the SEA algorithm, a popular method for comparing sets of ligands.
        \begin{boenumerate}\compresslist
            \item DeCAF gives better results for 23 out of 35 receptors.
            \item For targets with easily separable active and inactive datasets, SEA and DeCAF give similar results.
            \item In cases in which SEA fails to identify active molecules, our method performs substantially better.
        \end{boenumerate}
        
    }
            
    \headerbox{7. References}{name=references,column=0,span=1,below=introduction,above=bottom}{
        
        
        %\small % Reduce the font size in this block
        \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
        %\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
        
        
%           \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%           \bibliography{poster} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
    }
    
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```